# Am having issue implementing the javascript code with vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Am very new to vuejs.am trying to replicate the javascript with vue. where a user can toggle button. I have a list of buttons and I would like to toggle the active class but remove the active class from all other buttons.. Is there a better way of writtting the function without the querySelector?  Am really stuck..

```html
<template>
  <div @click="selectItem" class="menu-tabs">
    <button type="btn" class="menu-tab-item active" data-target="#remis-transfer"> Transfer
    </button>
    <button type="btn" class="menu-tab-item text-muted" data-target="#bank-transfer">
      Transfer Money
    </button>
    <button type="btn" class="menu-tab-item text-muted" data-target="#fueling">
      Fueling
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    selectItem(e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains("menu-tab-item") && !e.target.classList.contains("active")) {
        const target = e.target.getAttribute("data-target")
        menuTabs.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
        e.target.classList.add("active");
        const menuSection = document.querySelector(".menu-section");
        menuSection.querySelector(".menu-tab-content.active").classList.remove("active");
        menuSection.querySelector(target).classList.add('active');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, there is, https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        active: 0,
        buttonList: [
          {
            text: "Transfer",
            target: "#remis-transfer",
          },
          {
            text: "Transfer Money",
            target: "#bank-transfer",
          },
          {
            text: "Fueling",
            target: "#fueling",
          },
        ],
      };
    },
    methods: {
      selectItem(i) {
        this.active = i;
      },
    },
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="menu-tabs">
    <button
      type="btn"
      class="menu-tab-item"
      v-for="(item, index) in buttonList"
      :class="[{ active: active == index }, { 'text-muted': active != index }]"
      :data-target="item.target"
      :key="index"
      @click="selectItem(index)"
    >
      {{ item.text }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define some states like:

```
data() {
    return {
      myActiveClass: 'active',
      myMutedClass: 'text-muted'
    }
 },
```

and pass this myActiveClass and myMutedClass states to your elements like this:
class=`menu-tab-item ${myMutedClass} ${myActiveClass}`

with this approach, you can quickly achieve what you want. So when you want an element to not be active, in your function you can make myActiveClass = '', or if you want the text to lose muted class you can say myMutedClass = '' .
Just make sure to play with states in the way you want.